# document is not defined

Tags: javascript

Получаю ошибку:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

Путь до файла указан верно, скрипт работает с другими функциями, но глобальные переменные не видит.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Hello world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- my comment -->
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum <a href="" class="link">dolor</a> sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Ducimus voluptatem rerum consequatur possimus, commodi
      totam molestiae sed dignissimos alias aliquid sequi a nemo nulla provident
      nihil? Soluta cum libero fugiat?
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
console.log(document.body);
```

Comment: какой-то сборщик используете или просто 2 файла (файл **html** и файл **js**)?

Comment: просто два файла

Comment: а `window` тоже не видит?

Comment: да, тоже не видит

Comment: Вы точно не на сервере рендерите страницу?

Comment: liveserver использую

Comment: код запускается в браузере и в консоли браузера все работает, а редакторе нет

Comment: vscode. Переменную window тоже не видит. console.log(this) выдает Object [global]

Comment: ну тогда точно код запускается в среде сервера, попробуйте вариант, который я предложил в официальном ответе

Comment: window is not defined

Answer (score 1):

я не знаю как работает **liveserver** (скорее всего он работает как **SSR**),но объект `window` есть только у браузера, а Вы пытаетесь выполнить код в среде сервера. попытайтесь просто делать проверку на наличие `window`, например:

```
if (window) console.log(document.body);
```